# How to save Xcode Window Layout and Size

Tags: xcode, user-interface, layout, preferences

I've got my workspace windows set up like this:

[image: Workspace 1]

Then I Navigate away from my story board to replace the left window with some code so i Can compare two code documents like this:

[image: Workspace 2]

When I navigate back to my storyboard, it resets the document outline column to this:

[image]

How the frak do I configure window sizing presets? Coming from an Adobe background I'm used to having a preference somewhere that allows me to save interface layouts and sizing presets. The closest thing I can find is "behaviors", but this doesn't seem to control the sizing of columns and windows.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the best way to handle this is by using "Tabs"

I found [this](http://brian-webster.tumblr.com/post/22060296528/how-to-make-xcode-4s-ui-work-for-you-maybe) very helpful blog post.